# Correct syntax for operator >> overloading to members of nested class?

Tags: c++, class, nested, overloading, istream

I have **class Address** nested in **class Student**, and I want to feed each input line into the **class Student** with **operator>>** overloading through istream.

```
class Address {
public:
    ....

private:
    int house_no;
    string street;
    string city;
    string postcode
};


class Student {
public:
    ....
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& iss, Student& Obj) {
        iss >> Obj.roll_no >> Obj.name 
       >> Obj.addr.house_no >> Obj.addr.street >> Obj.addr.city >> addr.postcode;    //problem line
        return iss;
}

private:
    int roll_no;
    string name;
    Address addr;
};


//Sample line of test data (fields delimiter is comma):
1101, Alice Rilley, 421, Main St., New York, 230011
2202, Bert McDonald, 152, Railroad St., Madison, 120022
...
```

My chained istream (problem line) did not work out with error message as:

```
./include/Student.h: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Student&)’:
./include/Student.h:23:60: error: ‘int Address::house_no’ is private within this context
   23 |                 iss >> Obj.roll_no >> Obj.name >> Obj.addr.house_no >> ......
```

I found only one similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429868/how-to-overload-operator-in-nested-class) in SO, but it is for "**operator <<** " opposite to my need. And, it was quite difficult for me to digest.
What is the correct syntax for me to read in a line and feed the line into the object members (especially the **nested class Address**) of **class Student**? Thanks a lot!

Comment: imo the correct thing to do is implement the operator for Address and call that from the Student one. (but you can alternatively make your current operator friend of Address, but you'll need a forward declare to make it work etc, it doesnt feel as clean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the operator itself, but in the visibility of the members. You are using the `Address` class as a member of `Student`, but the `Address::house_no` member is not accessible from it (not only for the input operator).

One solution (a simple but bad one) would be to open the members of `Address`:

```
class Address {
public:
    ....

//private:
public:
    int house_no;
    string street;
    string city;
    string postcode
};
```

But a better approach would be to define an input operator for `Address`:

```cpp
class Address {
public:
    ....

private:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& iss, Address& Obj);

    int house_no;
    string street;
    string city;
    string postcode
};


class Student {
public:
    ....
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& iss, Student& Obj);

private:
    int roll_no;
    string name;
    Address addr;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& iss, Address& Obj) {
    iss >> Obj.house_no >> Obj.street >> Obj.city >> Obj.postcode;
    return iss;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& iss, Student& Obj) {
    iss >> Obj.roll_no >> Obj.name >> Obj.addr;
    return iss;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! To confirm: Should the overloading in class `Address` be `private`? I tried it in `public` which works too.

Comment: My fault: I've copied your code and didn't notice another problem. These operators are not member functions. They are free functions defined outside of the class. Friendship does not affect the visibility, so you may declare it in any section. See updates.

Comment: `Address::house_no` member is not accessible to `Student`, which helps me understand the problem in whole. Thanks a lot!